# lua_newstate vs lua_newthread

Tags: c++, multithreading, lua

I am trying to implement lua into my existing multi threaded application. I heard that lua was not thread safe I have been creating different `lua_State(s)` for different threads.

Looking through the lua header files I found `lua_newthread`. How would you implement that into an all ready threaded application. Do you create one `lua_State` and create separate `lua_newthread(s)` or would that lead to other issues?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Watch out, Lua threads are *not* operating system threads (despite the misleading name), only facilities in Lua itself (not in the host application) to execute code in an asynchronous fashion.

So the answer is: create one `lua_State` per thread in your application, and use a serialization library as middleware if you need to pass data between the states.

Comment: It's not really asynchronous; only one 'thread' (more commonly called [coroutines](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.11)) can be running at any point, and coroutine switching must be done explicitly with `coroutine.yield`.

Answer (score 9):

The answers thus far don't really provide an overview of the various ways to achieve parallel execution of chunks of lua, so here is my 2 cents on the topic of 'multi-threading' lua:

You can essentially think of a lua state/engine in two parts.  First, there is the global environment, which includes all the global variables, etc for the lua state.  And second, there is the execution stack, which expands and shrinks as functions call functions and your program executes.  To my knowledge, there are three ways to achieve parallel execution of multiple stream of lua:

1. The simplest is coroutines (which appears to be what lhf's answer is talking about), which can be achieved in pure lua using the coroutine library.  If you are familiar with cooperative multi-tasking, this is where each stream of execution needs to explicitly hand over the processor (or "yield") to the others periodically.  Coroutines share a single environment and global variable space, but each coroutine has a separate execution stack.  So in this way you can effectively have 2+ streams of lua execution that are active simultaneously, although only one executes at a given instant in time, of course, as there is only one OS thread doing the work.

PROS: simple to achieve with pure lua (no C code changes)

CONS: the inconvenience of having to place yield calls all over the place makes the code look nasty.  Also, longer tasks need to be broken up into tiny pieces, and if you are not really careful, poor thread latency can result if you ever do a longer chunk of work in a coroutine in between yield calls.  If you have calls to long-running C functions, there is no way to yield mid-run, so you are out of luck and all other lua has to wait.

2. The other extreme (as suggested by michaelmeyer) is to have multiple OS threads, with one dedicated lua state for each (returned by lua_newstate()).  This allows truly pre-emptive multi-tasking, including prioritization of real-time lua tasks over other long-running tasks in C or pure lua code.  In this case, each OS thread has its own environment and global variable space, as well as its own  execution stack.  This functionality can also be achieved without modification to the stock lua code (other than creating the OS threads and calling lua_newstate() for each one), and the separate lua engines/states have no direct interaction with each other so synchronization/mutex is not required to protect the lua environment.  But the hard part is sharing data across the different threads, as each thread has a whole new global variable space.  There are a number of clever ways to do this (e.g. lua lanes), including serialization of data back and forth, sharing data at the C-level user data objects with explicit synchronization in C, and others.

PROS: easy to achieve on stock lua code, and can take full advantage of an unlimited number of CPU cores

CONS: one of multiple clever strategies is required to share variables and data between threads/states, and this sharing generally requires explicit lua code each time you access a shared variable from lua, as well as some wasted or idle CPU cycles on serialization and synchronization.  It also uses a bunch more memory, which can become non-trivial on an embedded system: one project I work on only requires about 100kB of stack space for each OS thread, but each new lua environment to go with it uses an additional 1.5MB once it's loaded up with all the binding libraries and global context.

3. A nice compromise is to use the lua_newthread() to spawn a new state from an existing one, which will give you a newly created execution stack, but will share the existing environment and global variable space with the previous lua state.  You can then proceed to use the newly-created state on a different OS thread, allowing pre-emptive multi-threading and prioritization of real-time tasks with a more predictable worst-case latency.  But... in this case, you !must! implement the lua_lock() and lua_unlock() functions in C to provide mutex protection on the shared lua environment.  Under the hood, the lua VM is constantly calling these functions (which are defined to do nothing by default) to lock and unlock the environment to prevent corruption by other OS threads.  The huge advantage of this method is that various threads can run lua simultaneously against the same global variable space, and truly execute in parallel.  When a C function is called via your lua bindings, this is done with the environment unlocked, so as long as most of your computationally expensive work is done in these C functions you can even saturate a large number of CPU cores.  This can result is a much simpler programming flow, as longer operations (e.g. drawing calls, file system access, 2D/3D graphics operations, device driver access, etc.) no longer require complicated sequences of callbacks to avoid tying up the entire lua engine and killing the latency of your real-time tasks that are written in lua just like the rest of your application.

PROS: sharing of data is much simpler and has virtually no CPU overhead (although you still need to remain cognizant of other threads that might be writing a variable while you're reading, such as iterating through a table while another threads adds to it.)

CONS: there is a small amount of overhead of calling a mutex lock a massive number of times as your lua executes (in my case, this results in ~6% CPU overhead - a bit of a hit, but worth the cost).  Also, if you are trying to spread a huge amount of pure lua work across multiple cores, you will eventually hit a bottle neck due to the shared access to the lua environment - although in my experience, you don't generally spend most of your CPU cycles running pure lua.  You generally spend most of your CPU cycles in your C functions called by lua, during which you don't own the lock on the environment, which won't prevent code from running on other cores.

Comment: Awesome explanation! And very helpful advise about `lua_lock()` & `lua_unlock()` macros and the locking party when using coroutines in a multi-threaded environment.

Answer (score 8):

`lua_newstate` creates a new Lua states. Different states are completely separate.

`lua_newthread` creates a new *Lua* thread attached to a given Lua state. A Lua state can have multiple threads of execution inside the Lua VM, but they are not executed concurrently; they are *coroutines* and can share data..

Do not confuse Lua threads with operating-system threads.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an example of sharing data across parallel threads then here's something I cooked up recently: https://gitlab.com/awsdert/gasp

The basic premise is that the main thread (the one that started with "int main(...)") handles communication and memory allocations, lua is kept to one C thread and passed the necessary pointers during initialization that enable it to unknowingly communicate it's allocations to other threads, if those threads stored the initial pointer then they have a means of identifying when to change it, when an allocation is to occur then all threads are told to wait then once done they are told to continue, at this point they are told the new pointer which means they can update their current pointer before continuing. Because of the design it means threads can also communicate when they want to read/write to/from something by just grabbing the pointer of the thread holding authority over the pointer and sending the message to the main thread who then communicates to all threads, the threads that don't know the pointer to begin with can just report they're fine with it and continue on with their own business, the one/s that do know about it will report their fine with it and wait for the message to continue to be sent.