# Can many concurrent calls to the same overused function cause blocking in Lua?

Tags: lua, virtual-machine, callblocking

Lets say you have a complex Lua application, and there is some base function that different parts of your code call repeatedly.  It's a stateless function with little to no side effects, and fairly simple.

How does the virtual machine handle this?  Does it queue up all the calls, and let them run one by one, waiting for the function to to return before calling it again?  Or does it do some trickery to avoid this sort of situation?  What if the function had some big side effects, like print()?

Comment: Perhaps this is also relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26574705/lua-newstate-vs-lua-newthread.

Comment: Are you talking about a function written in Lua or a function written in C?

Comment: Lua, but would be interested in both answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lua is single threaded so every function call must return before the next one is called. If a function is blocked then so is the VM. The only way around that is coroutines or Lua lanes or C threads.